# Remove rows that have more than a threshold of missing values missing values

Tags: r

I have a matrix with some missing values

```
A <- array(c(1, NA, 3, NA, 4, 5, 7, NA, 2 ), dim=c(3,3))
```

I can delete all rows that has missing values using

```
B <- na.omit(A) or B <- A[!complete.cases(A),]
```

I can remove the columns having more than 50% of missing values using

```
B <- A[,colSums(is.na(A)) < nrow(A)/2]
```

Now my question is how can I delete rows that have more than 50% of missing values? I rried

```
B <- A[,rowSums(is.na(A)) < ncol(A)/2]
```

does not work. What options do I have apart from transposing the matrix which is too intensive for large matrices.

Comment: upvote for making a nice reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the row selector argument of `[`:

```
A[rowSums(is.na(A)) < ncol(A)/2, ]
```

Produces:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   NA    7
[2,]    3    5    2
```

Comment: Untested? for me it produces : [1] 3 5 2  for me.

Comment: @lovedynasty, reset `A` to be as you specified originally, and then copy and paste my code again.  I get the result as above.  I didn't manually make up the text for the answer (just copy paste from my terminal).

Comment: My bad ... there was additional brackets in A in question, which I now have edited.